# Get all names from object and it's children object

Tags: javascript, object, pug

[image: I posted a object down below]

I have struggled with this task for a while and decided that need your help. How can I get all names executed in line (html head tag body h1 div...).

I wrote a code using recursion method but somewhere fail. Executes 'Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined'. Could you tell mee where is mistake and hint to solve it.

```
"use strict";

var treeString;

var Node = require("./Node");

 function TreeView(result){
     treeString = "";
 createTreeView(result, 0);
}

 var createTreeView = function (current, level) {
     treeString += current.children;

     current.children.forEach(function(childObj) {
         createTreeView(childObj, level + 1);
     });
};

TreeView.prototype.toString = function (){
   return treeString;
};
// Exports
module.exports = TreeView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should iterate all dom elements. Paste into console and see what happens.

```
var currentNode,
    ni = document.createNodeIterator(document.documentElement, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);

while(currentNode = ni.nextNode()) {
    console.log(currentNode.nodeName);
```